# AWS Lambda - Function URL with params and char "=" returns error

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a Lambda that I use with the function URL, so I don't need to use API Gateway. However, a weird error occurs when I pass an param with "=" such as:

```
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.lambda-url.YYYY.on.aws/v1/product?limit=20&query=sku[EQUALS]=teste&sort=updated_at[DESC]&fields=sku,weight,client_id,price_list,stock_list,approved&offset=0
```

The `query=sku[EQUALS]=teste` is the problem.

The only solution is to never use "="?

It works with API Gateway, but not in direct function url, the handler is never called, so it's an AWS problem (or internal definition not listed on documentation).

Comment: The issue here looks like the lack of URL encoding. Putting `=` in the value of a query param is always tricky because sometimes it's impossible to determine if the `=` should be a part of value or signals the start of another value. Here you can find an example on how to do it in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode